# Xcode 10 beta iOS 12 not showing images

Tags: ios, image, beta

I have a issue with beta versions of Xcode and iOS. I have some png assets, and they work fine in simulator. But on device some of assets (not all, but most) are having problem being loaded correctly. In terminal I get errors like:

```
2018-08-14 15:53:06.554087+0200 Findlo[1896:230695] [framework] CoreUI: Encoded Deepmap blob version 1128416075 does not match with current version 4
2018-08-14 15:53:06.554132+0200 Findlo[1896:230695] [framework] CoreUI: Unable to decompress stream for CSI image block data. 'deepmap-lzfse'
```

And UIImage is created, but it's displayed as completely transparent image. What can I do to resolve this? I created all these images using Pixelmator (both working and not working)

Comment: Same issue with WatchOS 5 beta 6. Please file a bug. It will be a duplicate of mine (43215850), but duplicates will expedite a fix.

Comment: Any progress for this issue?

Comment: It started working with later iOS 12 versions.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting these exact errors trying to create an `SKSpriteNode` from a .png.  I believe this was caused if you had a mismatch in the version of the Xcode 10 beta and iOS 12 beta.  I had the latest Xcode 10 (beta 6) but a slightly older iOS 12 seed.  It was resolved when I updated to the latest iOS 12 beta (beta 10).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem, and I noticed something when going through my code in Github. When opening the project in the new Beta Xcode 10, the images that were not showing up have different constraints now. This is not a solution, but it may help us figure out why these bugs are occurring. I do not know why the constraints were switched. [image]

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same problem. I took a look at it for a few hours and couldn't see anything weird except the same consol messages you got. Next step was to figure out if iOS 12 did something wrong or Xcode 10. I ran all the beta versions and found that indeed it's Xcode that does something wrong.

- Beta1 OK
- Beta2 OK
- Beta3 OK
- Beta4 NOT OK
- Beta5 NOT OK
- Beta6 NOT OK

We concluded that it's not worth spending more time on it, it will start to work again in a later version of Xcode 10. It probably has something to do with the way Xcode tries to optimise the PNG compression or something similar.

**UPDATE** 
Tried it with Xcode GM and it works fine now. In all my projects.

Answer (score 0):

Convert images to *.png format and add to the project dir, not .xcassets catalog. It worked for me.

Comment: It's just a workoround. Such approach won't work with .pdf

Comment: Why are you talking about pdf? OP said: `I have some png assets`.

Comment: I answered for more general case to fix problem with images loaded from xcassets